# Partial selection on Inner Join

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need select ony on field to services, look:

```
  async find(): Promise<AccountEntity[]> {
    const result = await this.repository
      .createQueryBuilder("account")
      .select(['account', 'accountServices', 'service.description'])
      .leftJoinAndSelect("account.accountAndServices", "accountServices")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("accountServices.service", "service")
      .getMany();
    return result === undefined ? null : result;
  }
```

How to ? please.
I don't want null attributes to appear and I also want to choose which attributes to show
I need :

```
{
  "message": "",
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "STONES TECNOLOGIA LTDA",
      "accountAndServices": [
        {
          "service": {
            "name": "Construção de uma casa",
          },
          "date_initial": "2021-08-01T07:39:18.000Z",
          "date_final": "2021-08-01T07:39:20.000Z",
          "value": "10.00",
          "created_by": 1,
          "is_active": true,
          "id": 1,
          "pay_day": 10,
          "nfse": 0,
          "created_at": "2021-08-01T07:39:27.000Z",
        },
        {
          "service": {
            "name": "Desenvolvimento de sistemas",
          },
          "date_initial": "2021-08-01T07:40:01.000Z",
          "date_final": "2021-08-01T07:40:02.000Z",
          "value": "20.00",
          "created_by": 1,
          "is_active": true,
          "id": 2,
          "pay_day": 20,
          "nfse": 0,
          "created_at": "2021-08-01T07:40:11.000Z",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": null
}
```

I Need selection only field on entity join.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want so select some fields. In the whole query or only in the service table??
Can you share a SQL example or the expected result?

Comment: I don't want all the service fields, I want only a single field. I would like to select in each entity the fields that I want, and of course generate the json for me in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

[Select with innerJoin](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/876#issuecomment-433353229) you must use [`addSelect(...)`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md).

The *find* function must not manipulate any data and should return an array of `AccountEntity` (empty if not found):

```js
function find(): Promise<AccountEntity[]> {
    return this.repository
      .createQueryBuilder("a")
      .innerJoin("account.accountAndServices", "as")
      .innerJoin("accountServices.service", "s")
      .select(['a.id', 'a.name', 'a.status'])
      .addSelect(['as.date_initial', 'as.date_final', 'as.service_id', 'as.value', 'as.nfse', 'as.value', 'as.created_by', 'is_active', 'pay_day', 'created_at'])
      .addSelect(['s.name'])
      .getMany();
}
```

Note that to obtain the result from the function you must use `await`.
Moreover, surround it with `try` and `catch` for a better error handling.
Example:

```js
try {
    const accounts: AccountEntity[] = await find();
} catch(error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
}
```

To *transform* the array of `AccountEntity` to another *object*:

```js
function transform(accounts?: AccountEntity[]) {
    return {
        message: "",
        success: accounts !== undefined,
        data: accounts,
        errors: null
    };
}
```